# angularjs how to bind data in the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive like this.

```
app.directive('updateinfo', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      function update(){
         var str = '<input type="text" ng-model="scope.log1" />';
         element.html(str);    
      }
      update();
    }
    return {
      link: link
    };
});
```

The directive shows a text input box, but it does not show the `scope.log1`value and the changes made in the textbox are not reflected in the scope variable. I want to use the link function because I want to access other `scope variables`. Is there a way to use link function and still bind data to scope variable.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to use `$compile` if you want to directly modify the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must not write `scope` or `$scope` into the DOM.
Secondly, you need to compile your content

```
app.directive('updateinfo', function($compile) {
     function link(scope, element, attrs) {
          var str = '<input type="text" ng-model="log1" />';
          element.html(str);   
          $compile(element.contents())(scope);
     }
     return {
          link: link
     };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
.directive('updateinfo',['$compile', function($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      function update(){
         var str = '<input type="text" ng-model="log1" />';
         element.html(str);    
      }
      update();
      element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
    }
    return {
      link: link

    };
}]);
```